# Terraform module Issues - error No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a new bucket in AWS using terraform code. I have 3 files. main.tf - which has:

```
terraform {   
    backend "s3" {    
         bucket = "test-terraform-statev1"     
         key    = "terraform.tfstate"     
         region = "us-east-2"   
    }   
    
    required_providers {     
        aws = {       
            source  = "hashicorp/aws"       
            version = ">= 3.69"     
        }   
    } 
    
    required_version = ">= 1.0.10"
}

module "s3_bucket" {
    source = "./s3.tf"
}

output "s3_bucket_id" {
    value = module.s3_bucket.aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.id
}
```

s3.tf which has:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket" {
    bucket = "${var.bucket_name}"
    region = "us-east-2"
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "bucket_name" {
    type    = string
    default = "bucket_name"
}
```

and provider.tf

```
provider "aws" {
    access_key = "${var.aws_access_key}"
    secret_key = "${var.aws_secret_key}"
    token      = "${var.aws_session_token}"
    region     = "us-east-2"
}
```

( I gave actual values in the provider.tf for now)

I tried changing configuration like bucket name, variables, tags etc. but its not working at all. I tested whether credentials issue but was able to fetch buckets using AWS CLI with same details.

Comment: From which path you are running `terraform plan` ? Can you do an `ls -aR` there?

Comment: here is output last 2 lines ./.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/4.56.0/darwin_arm64:
.                                       ..                                      terraform-provider-aws_v4.56.0_x5

./storage:
.               ..              main.tf         s3.tf           variables.tf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to import a tf file as module.

Please note that module sources can be (as specified in [Terraform documentation: Modules sources](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/sources)):

> The module installer supports installation from a number of different
>
> source types.
> Local paths
>
> - Terraform Registry
> - GitHub
> - Bitbucket
> - Generic Git, Mercurial repositories
> - HTTP URLs
> - S3 buckets
> - GCS buckets
> - Modules in Package Sub-directories

So if you have `s3.tf`, `main.tf` and `variables.tf` in the same directory just edit `main.tf` by removing:

```
module "s3_bucket" {
    source = "./s3.tf"
}
```

And make the output:

```
output "s3_bucket_id" {
    value = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.id
}
```

So this means that you are putting your resources in the [root module](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules#the-root-module)

---

Or if you want to use sub-modules, create a direcory/folder in your path for example `modules/storage` and then move your `s3.tf` and `variables.tf` there so you would have:

```
├── main.tf
└── modules
    └── storage
        ├── s3.tf
        └── variables.tf
```

Then update the source in your module in `main.tf` to:

```
module "s3_bucket" {
    source = "./modules/storage"
}
```